# import from ES6 module to legacy js code

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-module-loader

I use babel.js and have a new module foo in my code

**foo.js:**

```
export function foo(number) {
    return number + 42;
}
```

And bunch of big old files where everything is global. And I need to call a foo function from that legacy code.

**bar.js:**

```
 ...
 var result = foo(0); 
 ...
```

But I can't just import foo cause then my bar.js will be a module and unavailable from other old code. Is there a way to import module 
and retain my bar.js global?

Comment: *"But I can't just import foo cause then my bar.js will be a module and unavailable from other old code"* You have to import the module file / somehow if you want to use it. What's the context? How can bar.js be used "globally" in the first case.

Comment: Which module loader are you using? Do you transpile to commonjs?

Comment: I use webpack. In bar.js a lot of global variable and function that used in other part of application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a somewhat similar problem recently. I ended up polluting `window` object with everything I need in legacy code.

I created separate `register.js` module for this purpose and included it to my webpack build:

```
import ClassA from './ClassA'
import ClassB from './ClassB'
import * as utils from './utils'

Object.assign(window, utils)
Object.assign(window, {ClassA, ClassB})
```

Comment: Great solution!